# How to construct a multimodal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume I have N normal distributions.

I want to sample and combine the values such that the resulting distribution is a multimodal distribution where each mode is at the average of one of the original normal distributions.

So if I have $X_i(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ $N$ random normal distiributions, I want to make a new variable:

$Y = F(X_i)$

Such that $F$ is multimodal with $N$ modes.

Comment: Isn't a weighted sum of probability density functions of $X_i$ good enough?

Comment: wouldn;t that end up being a new normal distribution by the central limit theorem?

Comment: No, why? Central limit theorem deals with the random variable which is a weighted sum of random variables. I'm talking about PDF being a weighted sum of PDFs. These are very different, unrelated things.

Comment: We will suppose that $Y = F(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = F(\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^N)$, but not $Y=F(X_i)$ - otherwise the algorithm will be harder.

Step 1: If $\mu_i = \mu_j$ for some $j > i$, we get rid of $X_j$. Thus we may assume that all $\mu_i$, $1 \le i \le N$ are distinct. 
 
Step 2: Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $Y_i = \mu_i + c_i(X_i - \mu_i)$ and take $c_i = \frac{1}{m \sigma_i}$. We have $Y_i \sim N(\mu_i, c_i^2 \sigma_i^2) = N(\mu_i,\frac{1}{m^2})$. 

Step 3: Find "big" $m$, "small" $\epsilon_i$ and some $p_i, i \le i \le N$ such that $\sum_i p_i (Y_i + \epsilon_i) $ is what you want.